Laravel custom admin authentication using repository pattern
This is my functionn for authenticating the user but it does not work I defined this function in the UserRepository
public function loginUser(array $data)
{
    if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $data['email'], 'password' => $data['password']])) {
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->user()->role != 'admin') {
            Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
            return false; // Unauthorized user
        }
        return true; // Login Successfull
    }
    return false; // Invalid credentials
}

This is my controller function. When I enter the correct email and password. it gives me an error of invalid credentials. I just want the user to access the dashboard with the help of custom authentication.
public function userLoggedin(Request $request)
{

    // Validate the incoming request data
    $data = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    // Attempt to log the user in via the repository
    if ($this->userRepo->loginUser($data)) {
        return redirect()->route("admin.dashboard")->with("success", "Admin logged in successfully");
    } else {
        return redirect()->route("admin.loginform")->with("error", "Invalid credentials or unauthorized access.");
    }
}

